# Matrix column spacing

Tags: plain-tex

I am using a matrix in `Plain TeX`, and the spacing between columns is too large. Since I'm also changing the paper size, the matrix runs off the side of the page. A minimal example is

```
\input eplain

$$
  A =
    \left\{
      \matrix{
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
      }
    \right\}
$$

\bye
```

I can shrink the columns by inserting an `\hskip` before each `&`, but that makes the source difficult to read. Is there a nicer way to control this spacing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Plain, not `eplain`. The definition of `\matrix` uses `\quad` between columns. You can define a new macro that takes another argument for the spacing:

```
\input eplain
\catcode`@=11
\def\xmatrix#1#2{\null\,\vcenter{\normalbaselines\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil$##$\hfil&&\hskip#1\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
      \mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}
      #2\crcr\mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}}}\,}
\catcode`@=12

$$
  A =
    \left\{
      \xmatrix{3pt}{
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
      }
    \right\}
$$

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can redefine `\quad` inside the group; this way, it is restored when the group is complete (originally, I had it redefined before the group and reset it manually after the group; thanks to morbusg for the reminder, saving me two lines of code).

```
\input eplain
$$
 \def\quad{\hskip1ex\relax}
  A =
    \left\{
      \matrix{
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
        (1&1&(1&0&0)^6&||&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1^{30})\cr
      }
    \right\}
$$
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: You could redefine the `\quad` inside the display, because it forms a group, the redefinition goes away automatically after the group (ie. `$$\let\quad\enspace ...$$`)